# How to do encryption like android's "PBEWithMD5AndDES" in flutter dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, cryptography, md5, des

I'm trying to recreate an existing mobile apps into flutter but struggling in the "PBEWithMD5AndDES" encryption on android which I can't seem to find similar way in dart.

This is so far what I've tried to achieve the same using Flutter_Des.dart, Password_Hash.dart and Crypto.dart library but still can't get the same output.

```dart
encryptPassword(String keyStr, String passwordStr) async {
    if (keyStr.length == 0 || passwordStr.length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    var generator = new PBKDF2(hashAlgorithm: md5);
    String saltStr = generateSaltBase64String();

    var hash = generator.generateBase64Key(keyStr, saltStr, round, keyLength);
    var encryptBase64 = await FlutterDes.encryptToBase64(passwordStr, hash.toString());

    return encryptBase64;
  }
```

Below is what I have currently on Android.

```java
KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(str.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        byte[] utf8 = password.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        enc = Base64.encode(enc, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return new String(enc);
```

I'm expecting the same output as android so my backend able to decrypt it.

Answer (score 3):

PBEWithMD5AndDES uses PBKDF1 to generate the key material (not PBKDF2). This gives you 128 bits of key material that you then use as two 64 bit halves as the key and the IV for DES.

Derive the key and IV as follows - I've plugged in some arbitrary values for iteration, password and salt and confirmed against JCrypto.

```
  int iterations = 31;

  List<int> salt = [0x21, 0x21, 0xf0, 0x55, 0xc3, 0x9f, 0x5a, 0x75];
  List<int> password = utf8.encode('test');

  List<int> saltedKey = password + salt;

  Digest d = md5.convert(saltedKey);
  for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
    d = md5.convert(d.bytes);
  }

  print(d);

  List<int> key = d.bytes.sublist(0, 8);
  List<int> iv = d.bytes.sublist(8, 16);
  print(key);
  print(iv);
```

I can't find a Dart implementation of DES which takes a key and IV as bytes. `triple_des` wants them as strings - i.e. it's dumbed down. Pointy castle doesn't do DES. FlutterDes also seems to want strings. You might be able to modify `triple_des` to take binary keys and IVs. Or use a different cipher.

Comment: Thanks richard, you're getting me closer to what im looking for. But I have no idea how to modify tripledes to take binary keys and IVs, still searching for better cipher libraries. I did try converting them to string but it seems like destroyed the actual to something else which not expected by the cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using flutter's methodchannel and call platform specific code to do the encryption and its working now. Thanks